# Github permission denied for new repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

**Please help!**
I have three free private Github repositories working fine on my windows 10 computer, and I have just created a new fourth repository, following the same steps I took when creating the previous three; but when I try to do the first push on this new repository, I get:

```
>     identity_sign: private key /c/Users/EBC/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>     fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I know my ssh key is working fine since I can push code on any of the previous repositories without any issues, and I am using the exact same key. I even tried to add it as a new key in Github, but got a: "Key is already in use" message.

At first I thought I have reached the free repository limit, but according to this: https://github.blog/2019-01-07-new-year-new-github/, there´s no limit for free private repositories. So, what´s going on? 
Any ideas will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: ensure the new repository was created from your account, if not ask for access to the repository

Comment: Hi Ankidaemon, I did create this repo from my account directly on Github, and It´s listed alongside my other three repos. I even deleted it and then recreated it, in case something didn´t quite clicked... but to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else: The problem was that that I had my ssh key files mixed up. I used Windows Git Bash to try every key in my system until I found the one that Github accepted, by using the following git bash command:
$ ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/Path_to_folder_containing_ssh_keys/id_rsa git@github.com
Hi archmaster01! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
Cheers!